# Separate array from json and store to db

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-json

I have a json coming from web server as follows:

```
 "data": {
        "classes": [
            {
                "subject_name": "Chemistry",
                "class_id": "48",
                "class_division": "A",
                "map_id": "44",
                "teacher_name": "Principal",
                "subject_id": "7",
                "teacher_id": "1",
                "class_name": "1",
                "subject_code": "CHE"
            },
            {
                "subject_name": "Biology",
                "class_id": "48",
                "class_division": "A",
                "map_id": "33",
                "teacher_name": "Principal",
                "subject_id": "8",
                "teacher_id": "1",
                "class_name": "1",
                "subject_code": "BIO"
            }
        ],
        "token": "4A48B90CF31D582FAB73D283FA72380E"
```

I want to store class information in the database. Here in the classes array there is two objects it may differ according to the input. So how may separate each field in the array.

Comment: you can get each json object in the classes array and store it in your db

Comment: [json parsing in android](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=json%20parsing%20in%20android) is too easy, You can try it by yourself, and if you have any doubt on that you can come to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) for clarification.

Comment: FYI, [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) is forum used to discussion, it will not provide you complete tutorial.

Comment: alright, I'll try myself.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you hold that json in a String object called jsonResponse it would be as follows:

```
JSONObject json = new JOSNObject(jsonResponse);

JSONArray classes = json.getJSONArray("classes");

for (int i=0;i<classes.length();i++){

    JSONObject classesObj = classes.getJSONObject(i);

    /**
     * Next you would process your classesObj as you require.
     * Remember classesObject is a JSONObject
     */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to retrieve information aka parse that json data object.
There are different ways to do that using third party tools such as Jackson and Gson is the best approach, yet more complicated. So start with JSONObject and JSONArray.

convert json response to JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
```

get class array

```
JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("class");
```

iterate through jsonArray and get each object:

```
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
   JSONObject innerJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String subject_name = innerJson.get("subject_name");
   ....
   //write to database
}
```

On first iteration you will get first object then you can get its fields and write to database, on the next iteration you will get second object.

This method is just a demonstration, it works but is not effective